# Best way to find a point near all four points known coordinates

Tags: python

I have the coordinates of four points. Can anyone help me find the coordinates of one point that satisfies the condition: the distances from the finding point to four input points are in the range of 1.9 and 2.5?

```
import numpy as np

dist_min = 1.9
dist_max = 2.5
# this show no points satisfied
input_points1 = [[ 7.57447956,  6.67658376, 10.79921475],
                [ 8.98026868,  7.69010703, 12.89377068],
                [ 6.22242062,  7.73362942, 12.87947421],
                [ 10.0000000,  9.00000000, 8.500000000]]
#this has
input_points2 = [[ 7.57447956,  6.67658376, 10.79921475],
                 [ 8.98026868,  7.69010703, 12.89377068],
                 [ 6.22242062,  7.73362942, 12.87947421],
                 [ 6.22473072,  4.74175054, 12.96455411]]

def Distance(point1, point2):
    return np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2)
```

Comment: Just an idea. what about making a sphere around each point radius 2.5, and seeing if they intersect? if so, you have your point. If not, make the same circles for radius 1.9 and test again. Would that work?

Comment: That's called linear programming. In what context are you doing this? Is it for an assignment or for work?

Comment: Is this one point that is at most 2.5 units away from all 4 points and is also at least 1.9 units away from all 4?

Comment: This is distance between points: [2.718572605732653,
 2.6968293096668625,
 4.070356359800834,
 2.758228509302943,
 4.6969024203481196,
 5.920607635551088]. The last distance implies no point met the conditions.

Comment: @flakes and Ric, I mean the distances from the satisfied point to all four input points are in the range of 1.9 and 2.5. I change the coordinates of the last point. I think it is possible to find a point based on the second input list.

Comment: @Shmack, no.  input_points1 and  input_points2 are independent.

Comment: What @RicVillalba is saying is that, if you want your target to be within 2.5 of each input, then it follows that **every pair** of points must be **at most** 2.5 * 2 = 5.0 from each other. Otherwise, every point that's close enough to one of the points in that pair, is too far from the other.

Comment: I intuitively want to compute the centroid, then take that "midpoint" and some arbitrary point and compute the distance between the 2 to see if it falls within the threshold to see if there exists a point. If there exists a point, its the computed centroid point. The problem is I don't know how the formula changes for a 3d space. A 2d space doesn't look toooooo bad. Based on the distance between the centroid point and the arbitrary point, you could determine a loose formula for all points that exists within the range. Most of the time the pattern is like computing the jacobian matrix.

Comment: I'm afraid that the centroid approach cannot be of use in each case. Suppose all your points are very close (much less than dist_min). Even in that event there could be points that meet criteria, but these are well outside the convex hull of the given points. (i.e. a point that is almost at dist_max of the centroid).

Comment: @RicVillalba I'd need a diagram. Maybe some example points to plug into desmos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a method that finds a random point:

```
import numpy as np


dist_min = 1.9
dist_max = 2.5
# this show no points satisfied
input_points1 = [[ 7.57447956,  6.67658376, 10.79921475],
                [ 8.98026868,  7.69010703, 12.89377068],
                [ 6.22242062,  7.73362942, 12.87947421],
                [ 10.0000000,  9.00000000, 8.500000000]]
#this has
input_points2 = [[ 7.57447956,  6.67658376, 10.79921475],
                 [ 8.98026868,  7.69010703, 12.89377068],
                 [ 6.22242062,  7.73362942, 12.87947421],
                 [ 6.22473072,  4.74175054, 12.96455411]]

def Distance(point1, point2):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(point1) - np.array(point2))


def find_point(input_points):
    dmax = max([Distance(input_points[i], input_points[j]) 
     for i in range(len(input_points)-1) 
     for j in range(i+1, len(input_points))]) 

    if dmax > 2 * dist_max:
        return None

    found = False
    while not found:
        ip = np.random.choice(len(input_points))
        p = np.random.normal(size=3)
        r = np.random.uniform(dist_min, dist_max)
        x = p / np.linalg.norm(p) * r + np.array(input_points[ip])
        found = True
        for i in input_points:
            d = Distance(i, x)
            if d <= dist_min or d >= dist_max:
                found = False
                continue

    return(x)

a = find_point(input_points1)
print(a)  
# NONE

b = find_point(input_points2)
print([Distance(i, b) for i in input_points2])
# [2.4877643881304805, 2.1439232926982417, 2.2860134633791795, 1.9466840567560841]
```

Comment: Better to add a counter to raise an exception if no point were found after n iterations.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you could use a [K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) (link to Wikipedia) function for with just 1 centroid and then check that the point's distance is the right distance away from all the points in the data. Perhaps not the most elegant or efficient solution, but it should work.

K-Means Code adapted from [this tutorial on K-Means](https://pythonalgos.com/introduction-to-machine-learning-k-means/):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# data is whatever set of points you have
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# fit k means with 1 centroid lol
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=1)
labels=k_means.fit_predict(df)
centroid = k_means.cluster_centers_[:,0]

# compare to all points
for point in data:
    assert distance(point, centroid) >= 1.9
    assert distance(point, centroid) <= 2.5
```